# Heroku deployment of a Spark (web server) fails due to a faulty import?

Tags: java, heroku

I am trying to get a fairly simple Spark (web server) app deployed on Heroku. I think I've got everything setup correctly.

Once the app is loaded, it's main method fires correctly, but immediately fails with:

```
"2017-04-04T22:28:58.854643+00:00 app[web.1]: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: spark/Spark"
```

Accessing pschooser.herokuapp.com/choose/ should display a web page. However when the server is starting up it tries to call a static method provided by Spark, "getHerokuAssignedPor()" which leads it to fail because it cannot find the package.

The package is included with this line: "import static spark.Spark.*;" which works locally. Spark is defined correctly (I believe) in the Maven file.

I have searched a lot and can't find any useful clues.

Here's the source code for the main class with the main method:

```
package edu.brandeis.cosi12b.sparkdemo;
import static spark.Spark.*;


// https://sparktutorials.github.io/2015/08/24/spark-heroku.html
// https://sparktutorials.github.io/2015/06/01/spark-freemarker.html
// https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    port(getHerokuAssignedPort());

    StudentDirectory sd = new StudentDirectory();
    sd.readStudentInfoFile();
    StudentChooserServer sc = new StudentChooserServer(sd);
    sc.launch();
  }

  static int getHerokuAssignedPort() {
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
    if (processBuilder.environment().get("PORT") != null) {
      return Integer.parseInt(processBuilder.environment().get("PORT"));
    }
    return 4567; // return default port if heroku-port isn't set (i.e. on
                 // localhost)
  }

}
```

Comment: What's the command in your `Procfile`? Have you see this sample https://github.com/heroku/java-getting-started

Comment: web: java -jar target/SparkDemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar